# Show that $\mathbb R^3$ is the direct sum of two of its subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let $U$ and $V$ be finite dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$ such that $\dim (U)=1$ and
$\dim (V)=2$. Want to show that $\mathbb R^3$ is the direct sum of $U$ and $V$. 
How can we show that $\dim(U \cap V)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because it doesn't have to be true. Suppose that
$$U=\{(x,0,0)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}$$and that$$W=\{(x,y,0)\,|\,x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

Comment: so can it be true if $U$ is not a subset of $W$ ?

Comment: @Karen If $\dim U=1$ and $\dim W=2$, then $\dim(U\cap W)=0$ if and only if $U\varsubsetneq W$.